# how to set bug tracker url in setup.py script

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I have just discovered the pypi web UI have a field 'Bug tracker URL' in edit of egg metadata.

This field exists so I guess it is supported in setup.py but I can't find anything about this using google.

So the question how do I set up this field in my setup.py so when doing a dist release on pypi it can be automaticly filled.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The entry is called `bugtrack_url`, but it's not being picked up from `setup.py`.

From [context](https://twitter.com/jezdez/status/274420414422335488) and [code](https://bitbucket.org/loewis/pypi/commits/29c38d0902719c46d7378bc19e13cb9f15c65d31) I understand it was intended to be used through-the-web on PyPI only, as per-project metadata, and not the usual per-release information.

The field is now considered a [legacy field](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/233) (hardcoded to `None`) and you instead add such information through the [Project-URL list](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#project-url-multiple-use), which you can set in `setuptools` via the [`project_urls` entry](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#project-urls):

```
    project_urls={
        'Documentation': 'https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/',
        'Funding': 'https://donate.pypi.org',
        'Say Thanks!': 'http://saythanks.io/to/example',
        'Source': 'https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/',
        'Tracker': 'https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues',
    },
```

This option was [finally added to `setuptools` in November 2017](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/commit/df2246449c271c07586bcecc3eaa36e9b0e94e3d), and landed in version 38.3.0.

Answer (score 6):

## Bug tracker URL on PyPi project

In setup.py use [project_urls](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#project-urls) in the setup :

```
setup(
...
    project_urls={
        'Documentation': 'https://readthedocs.io/',
        'Funding': 'https://donate.pypi.org',
        'Say Thanks!': 'http://saythanks.io/to/example',
        'Source': 'https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/',
        'Tracker': 'https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues',
    },
...
)
```

The dict order is kept but listed in [reversed on PyPi](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/3097):

[image]

## About PyPi `bugtracker_url` legacy code

[pypa/warehouse Issue #233](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/233#issuecomment-37069593)

> bugtrack_url: IIRC it was something added by the PyPI maintainers to help projects, but in parallel PEP 345 introduced Project-URL which was intended to cover source code repository, bug tracker, mailing list, etc. If PEP 426 or one of its companion keeps Project-URL (and maybe improves it with defined labels for common sites, e.g. "repository"), then this special case becomes redundant.

And

> At the moment, it looks like this is hardcoded to None in their API. I guess they left the field for backwards compatibility when they migrated...

Comment: Keeping dict order wasn't a given in Python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8 - it works since ca. version 3.6