# How do you set the `bugtrack_url` field in pypi metadata?

Tags: python, pypi

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitenoise/json returns some metadata. I'm not the maintainer of that module, but I would like to help them find out how to set the `bugtrack_url` field for that package.

Python's [PEP-0345](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#project-url-multiple-use) references a "Project-URL multi-use field", which can be set by "a string containing a browsable URL and a label for it" and gives the concrete example:

> Bug Tracker, http://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issues/

However, it's not possible to set this via setup.py, and it's not easy to find how to set this via the pypi admin interface, so I guess what I'm asking is: can anyone give some step-by-step instructions with how to set this through the PyPI admin interface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set bug tracker url in setup.py script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459828/how-to-set-bug-tracker-url-in-setup-py-script)

Comment: The question is indeed similar, though I'm not sure the accepted answer is  correct any more, since it's made 4.5 years ago and the [whitenoise author](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise/issues/155#issuecomment-334828584) can't find a way to set it via the UI now.