# How To Set Project Links in PyPI

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

How do I add links under the `Project Links` section of my [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14460216/2961550) but was a bit difficult to find, so hopefully this one is a bit easier.

PyPI pulls these links from the [`project_urls`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#project-urls) metadata.

In your `setup.py` file, call `setuptools.setup()` with the `project_urls` argument as a dictionary of title-url pairs.

```py
import setuptools

project_urls = {
  'Link 1': 'https://mygreatsite.com',
  'Link 2': 'https://anothersite.com'
}

setuptools.setup( other_arguments, project_urls = project_urls )
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer. I seems like it is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I didn't know what the etiquette for accepting your own answer was.

Comment: As far as I know, it is perfectly fair to answer your own questions, it is even fair to ask a question with the intent to answer it yourself and accept your own answer. The only thing that matters is the value of the content (good question + good answer). -- The accepted check mark helps seeing which questions are closed cases, this way we know there is no need to open the question and answer it (since it already has a good answer).

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know for which URL identifier which icon is used on PyPI,e.g. if you write

```py
project_urls = {
  'Twitter': 'https://twitter.com/PyScaffold',
}
```

you will see the Twitter bird on PyPI, e.g. https://pypi.org/project/PyScaffold/.

In order to see the available icons and when there are set, just check out [this file](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/blob/01f87cfdb6275a8c8bc11b838618df246fc10fec/warehouse/templates/packaging/detail.html)(`/warehouse/templates/packaging/detail.html`) from the [PyPI source code](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse).

Answer (score 8):

Poetry [does this a bit differently](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#description), but it's the same idea.

You can put some basic info in the main part of your pyproject.toml file, under `[tool.poetry]`. Something like:

```
[tool.poetry]
homepage = "https://free.law/projects/x-ray"
repository = "https://github.com/freelawproject/x-ray"
documentation = "https://github.com/freelawproject/x-ray/blob/main/README.md"
```

And if you want even more URLs, you can do something like:

```
[tool.poetry.urls]
"Organisation Homepage" = "https://free.law/"
"Change Log" = "https://github.com/freelawproject/x-ray/blob/main/CHANGES.md"
Issues = "https://github.com/freelawproject/x-ray/issues"
Funding = "https://www.courtlistener.com/donate/?referrer=pypi-xray"
```

There's a list of special values that'll get you icons, but it seems like you can put whatever you want here and Poetry will be happy. If Pypi doesn't know what the link is, it'll just put a generic icon next to it.

Here's the list of things that get icons:

https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/blob/main/warehouse/templates/packaging/detail.html

Comment: There's also example projects that show many of the icons: https://pypi.org/project/links-demo/